# What's the use of 'name' when I can set 'filename' in webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

As we know, `webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin` is used to extract common parts of multiple js files, and the name of the extracted file is determined by `name`, or `filename` if it's available.

For example, the following plugin configuration will result in a file called `common.js`.

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'common',
    filename: 'common.js',
    minChunks: 2,
})
```

But when I removed the line `name: 'common'`, an error occurred:

```
Error: You did not specify any valid target chunk settings.
Take a look at the "name"/"names" or async/children option.
```

I don't understand why `name` is mandatory, because `filename` and `name` seem to have the same functionality: set the name of the generated file. So if I have set `filename`, `name` should no longer be necessary any more. But it's not the case. Can anyone tell me what's its use here?